# Converting list from one class to another

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to convert a group a complex list in C# (with Linq)

```
public class classA    
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int id { get; set; }    
    public string phone { get; set; }    
    public string interest { get; set; }    
}
```

My first class is `classA` where it contains many list of elements like below.

```
List<classA> obj = new List<classA>();
obj.Add(new classA { id = 1, Name = "a", phone = "321", interest = "Playing" });    
obj.Add(new classA { id = 1, Name = "2", phone = "123", interest="Tv" });
```

From this I need to group by using the id, So I've used `Linq`

```
 var item = obj.GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(ac => ac.ToList()).ToList();
```

I've another class called `classB` which hold's the values others than id from the `classA` (where it'd be hold all subset of different attributes)

```
public class classB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string interest { get; set; }
}
```

My Final Class looks likes,

```
public class Final
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<classB> details { get; set; }

    public Final()
    {
        details = new List<classB>();
    }
}
```

My requirements are, after grouping the `classA` based on `id`, I need to convert that into my `final` class.

So I did like below,

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    List<classA> obj = new List<classA>();
    obj.Add(new classA { id = 1, Name = "a", phone = "321", interest = "Playing" });
    obj.Add(new classA { id = 1, Name = "b", phone = "123", interest = "Tv" });
    obj.Add(new classA { id = 2, Name = "c", phone = "12322", interest = "Tv" });
    obj.Add(new classA { id = 3, Name = "d", phone = "12333", interest = "Tv" });

    var item = obj.GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(ac => ac.ToList()).ToList();
    List<Final> finalobjList = new List<Final>();

    foreach (var report in item)
    {

        Final finalObj = new Final();
        foreach (var result in report)
        {
            finalObj.id = result.id;
        }

        var data = report.Select(x => new classB { Name = x.Name, phone = x.phone, interest = x.interest }).ToList();
        finalObj.details = data;
        finalobjList.Add(finalObj);

    }

    Console.WriteLine(finalobjList.Count());
}
```

I believe there is another easy way to achieve this using `linq` without using `foreach` multiple times

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Why `foreach (var result in report)` if you only set the same member `finalObj.id = result.id;` again and again? - I guess you are fooking for `var finalobjList = obj.GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(x => new Final() { id = x.Key, details = x.Select(y => new classB() { Name = y.Name }).ToList() } ).ToList();`

Comment: You can't assign a `string Name` from classA to an `int Name` on classB...

Comment: @RufusL - there are a couple of errors in his classes - i guess just copy/paste errors and/or fake data errors

Comment: @RufusL I've corrected the typo

Comment: @RandRandom your solution works perfectly, Please provide your answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var finalobjList = obj.GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(x => new Final() { id = x.Key, details = x.Select(y => new classB() { Name = y.Name }).ToList() } ).ToList();
```

(Code only answer - please dont hate me)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use your existing code except when you do your `Select`, select a new `Final` and use the group's `Key` for the `Id`, and convert the `ac.ToList` to a list of `ClassB` for the `Details`:

```
var item = obj
    .GroupBy(a => a.id)
    .Select(ac =>
        new Final
        {
            Id = ac.Key,
            Details = ac.Select(a =>
                new classB {interest = a.interest, phone = a.phone, Name = a.Name})
                .ToList()
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var items = (from a in obj
 group new classB {Name = a.Name, phone = a.phone, interest = a.interest} by  a.id into aa
 select new Final { id = aa.Key, B= aa.ToList()}).ToList();
```

Comment: An explanation of the code would be nice - your reputation Means, you should know that.